# String.Format decimal with both thousand separators and forced decimal places

Tags: c#, string, parsing, decimal

I'd like to `String.Format` a decimal so that it has both thousand separators and forced decimal places (3).

For example:

Input:

```
123456,12
78545,8
```

Output:

```
123.456,120
78.545,800
```

I have tried

```
String.Format("{0:0.0,000}", input);
```

but this only gives the thousand separators but doesn't **force** the decimal places.

Comment: The custom numeric formats avoid taking a dependency on whether your culture formats the decimal point with a period or a comma.  That would be painful.  Use, say, "{0:#,##0.000}" instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a *[custom numeric format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)* string a period (`.`) is used for a "localized decimal separator". Ie. even if your current locale uses a comma as a decimal separator you should use a period in a format string. Similarly comma (`,`) is used for the localised thousands separator.

As your format puts the comma *after* the period things are going to get confused (thousands separators don't apply after the decimal point).

So try:

```
 String.Format("{0:#,##0.000}", input);
```

(Using `#` for digits to only include if `input` is large enough.)

Answer (score 4):

```
String.Format("{0:N3}", input)
```

See the [N format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#NFormatString)

Answer (score 2):

Either:

```
string.Format("{0:N3}", input)
```

Or explicitly (not taking into account the current culture):

```
string.Format("{0:#,##0.000}", input)
```