# Label StringFormat 1000000 to 1.000.000 in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, string-formatting

I have `<Label Text="{Binding Item.O_SALDO , StringFormat = ' {0:N0} '}" TextColor="#006BE6" Font="Bold, 16" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="End" />`

and my output is ex 1,000,000 but i want to have stringformat 1.000.000

Comment: this is because your device is using a culture that uses "," for the group separator.  If you change the culture to one that uses "." the format should change.  You should generally respect the convention of the user's culture setting unless you have a really good reason not to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475146/string-format-decimal-with-both-thousand-separators-and-forced-decimal-places

Comment: my app is not for usa ,uk culture because that i need to change the format. In my culture , mean decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution to achiever that .

The Xaml Code as follow :

```
<Label BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" 
        Text="{Binding ModelValue}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  FontSize="Large" TextColor="Black" />
```

Create a method to convert `int` value to needed format `string` :

```
private string ConvertIntToFormatSrting(int num)
{
    NumberFormatInfo nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
    nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
    string result = number.ToString("N0");

    return result;
}
```

Therefore in **MainPage** :

```
public string ModelValue { set; get; }
private int number { set; get; }

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    number = 1000000;

    ModelValue = ConvertIntToFormatSrting(number);

    Console.WriteLine("------"+ ModelValue);

    BindingContext = this;
}
```

The **effect** :

[image]